# Laravel 5.2 : How to retrieve data from one to one eloquent (hasOne) Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, one-to-one

I have two Models:
1. Course.
2. Fee.

One course has only one fee. While giving input it's completely ok but when I tried to access the fee data, it's showing nothing in fee's column . How do I solve it?

Course Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table='courses';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];


    public function fee(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Fee');
    }

}
```

Fee Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fee extends Model
{
        protected $table='fees';
    protected $fillable = ['fee','course_id'];
    public function course()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Course');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function listofCourse(){
        $course=\App\Course::all();
        return view('listofCourse',compact('course'));
    }
```

View Page:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Course Details </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="container">
<h3> Student Details </h3>
      <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Serial No</td>
            <td>Course Name</td>
            <td>Course Fee</td>


        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php $i=1; ?>
        @foreach($course as $row)

          <tr>
            <td>{{$i}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->name }}</td>

            <td>    @if($row->course)
                  {{$row->course->fee}}
                   @endif</td>


             </tr>
          <?php $i++; ?>

        @endforeach
        </tbody>


      </table>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your situation. It looks like you are calling a method 'course' on a 'course'

Comment: I want to access fees table data using courses table where id matches with course_id.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you have written the relationship wrongly... just do this.

Keep in Mind, `Course Has The Fee` means `Course` is must, so relation should start from `Course` side towards `Fee`.

**Your Course Model**

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table='courses';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];


    public function fee(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Fee','course_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

**Your Fee Model**

```
class Fee extends Model
{
    protected $table='fees';
    protected $fillable = ['fee','course_id'];
    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTO('App\Course', 'course_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Now you can get the relationship by doing this.**

```
public function listofCourse(){
        $course=\App\Course::with('fee')->get();
        // doing this for dumping purpose
        echo "<pre>"; 
        print_r($course->toArray()); // you will see the `fee` array
        echo "</pre>"; 
        die();
        return view('listofCourse',compact('course'));
}
```

Comment: @Andrew please explain your question, 
can you share your Data Array? so I can guide you accordingly

Comment: @Qazi thanks turns out i was using the wrong relationship, (i have a belongsToMany and extra columns in the pivot table) All sorted now...